# Overriding and accessing abstract class properties in child class in PHP

Tags: php

```
interface A
{
    public function method1();
    public function method2();
}

abstract class B implements A
{
    public $publicc = 2;
    public function method1()
    {
        echo "in method1 of B<br>";
    }
}

class C extends B
{
    public $publicc = 4;
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function method2()
    {
    }

    public function method1()
    {

        echo $this->publicc + parent::$publicc;  // error for using parent::$publicc
    }
}

$obj = new C();
$obj->method1();
```

But php throws error echo $this->publicc + parent::$publicc. I just want to get parent class $publicc property directly that has value 2, **Without using any accessor method**. Is there a way to do this in php?

Comment: You cant make a call like "$this->publicc + parent::$publicc". What are you doing there? And what actually is your question?

Comment: I think question is fairly simple. If I want to access abstract class B property $publicc in its child class which is overriding it. what I need to do? It is a perfect answer if you say that it cannot be done. Because I dont know whether it can be done or not

Comment: I can only say that extends is very evil although you read about it in almost every textbook.

Comment: @bub, What? Extension is a perfectly valid and widely used programming paradigm, that helps to avoid a lot of code repetition.

Comment: @dan08 haha, I knew that someone will talk like that. Just use a new perspective. If it is widley used pp so that still doesen't  mean that its valid and perfect. In real world you never extends parents to get children and you never extend vehicles to get cars or bikes. Just think about it. You dont need to use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what publicc exactly holds but a constant might suit your needs?

```
interface A
{
    public function method1();
    public function method2();
}

abstract class B implements A
{
    const PUBLICC = 2;
    public function method1()
    {
        echo "in method1 of B<br>";
    }
}

class C extends B
{
    const PUBLICC = 4;
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function method2()
    {
    }

    public function method1()
    {

        echo self::PUBLICC + parent::PUBLICC;  // error for using parent::PUBLICC
    }
}

$obj = new C();
$obj->method1();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a static property. If it is a property you want to access without an instance, that usually indicates a candidate for a static variable.

```
abstract class B implements A
{
    protected static $publicc = 2;
...
}

class C extends B
{
    public $publicc = 4;
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function method2()
    {
    }

    public function method1()
    {

        echo $this->publicc + parent::$publicc;  // error for using parent::$publicc
    }
}
```